# The remote authentication server is not available when recovering Bitbucket from AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitbucket, devops

After creating a test instance from an AMI of a prod instance of Bitbucket, authentication no longer works. The prod setup is running Bitbucket Server 5.0.1 and is authenticating using Azure AD.  When trying to log onto the test instance with Azure credentials, we get the error: "The remote authentication server is not available. Please try again later."

Also, we get the following logs:

```
2021-08-23 22:13:46,109 DEBUG [http-nio-7990-exec-6] @71MEL3x1333x433x0 1ix7xj 52.56.83.91,172.31.21.120 "POST /j_atl_security_check HTTP/1.1" c.a.s.i.a.PluginHttpAuthenticationFailureHandler onAuthenticationFailure - delegating to com.atlassian.stash.internal.auth.ScmAuthenticationFailureHandler
2021-08-23 22:13:46,109 DEBUG [http-nio-7990-exec-6] @71MEL3x1333x433x0 1ix7xj 52.56.83.91,172.31.21.120 "POST /j_atl_security_check HTTP/1.1" c.a.s.i.a.PluginHttpAuthenticationFailureHandler onAuthenticationFailure - delegating to com.atlassian.stash.internal.auth.BasicAuthChallengeFailureHandler
2021-08-23 22:13:46,109 DEBUG [http-nio-7990-exec-6] @71MEL3x1333x433x0 1ix7xj 52.56.83.91,172.31.21.120 "POST /j_atl_security_check HTTP/1.1" c.a.s.i.a.PluginHttpAuthenticationFailureHandler onAuthenticationFailure - delegating to com.atlassian.stash.internal.auth.RedirectingAuthenticationFailureHandler
2021-08-23 22:13:46,109 DEBUG [http-nio-7990-exec-6] @71MEL3x1333x433x0 1ix7xj 52.56.83.91,172.31.21.120 "POST /j_atl_security_check HTTP/1.1" c.a.s.i.a.PluginHttpAuthenticationFailureHandler onAuthenticationFailure - com.atlassian.stash.internal.auth.RedirectingAuthenticationFailureHandler handled authentication failure
2021-08-23 22:13:47,282 DEBUG [http-nio-7990-exec-4] @71MEL3x1333x437x0 52.19.35.158,172.31.7.76 "GET /rest/remote-event/1/status HTTP/1.1" c.a.b.i.c.s.CrowdSsoAuthenticationHandler Skipping Crowd SSO as it is not enabled
2021-08-23 22:13:47,282 DEBUG [http-nio-7990-exec-4] @71MEL3x1333x437x0 52.19.35.158,172.31.7.76 "GET /rest/remote-event/1/status HTTP/1.1" c.a.s.i.i18n.PluginI18nService No values found in any valid locale for key ProviderManager.providerNotFound and locales [en_US, en]
2021-08-23 22:13:47,298 DEBUG [http-nio-7990-exec-1] @71MEL3x1333x438x0 52.19.35.158,172.31.7.76 "GET /rest/remote-event/1/status/9fc15922-ffb1-3c9e-8121-679df18b26d7 HTTP/1.1" c.a.b.i.c.s.CrowdSsoAuthenticationHandler Skipping Crowd SSO as it is not enabled
2021-08-23 22:13:47,298 DEBUG [http-nio-7990-exec-1] @71MEL3x1333x438x0 52.19.35.158,172.31.7.76 "GET /rest/remote-event/1/status/9fc15922-ffb1-3c9e-8121-679df18b26d7 HTTP/1.1" c.a.s.i.i18n.PluginI18nService No values found in any valid locale for key ProviderManager.providerNotFound and locales [en_US, en]
2021-08-23 22:13:51,545 DEBUG [http-nio-7990-exec-10] @71MEL3x1333x439x0 52.17.236.147,172.31.7.76 "GET /login HTTP/1.1" c.a.b.i.c.s.CrowdSsoAuthenticationHandler Skipping Crowd SSO as it is not enabled
2021-08-23 22:13:51,545 DEBUG [http-nio-7990-exec-10] @71MEL3x1333x439x0 52.17.236.147,172.31.7.76 "GET /login HTTP/1.1" c.a.s.i.i18n.PluginI18nService No values found in any valid locale for key ProviderManager.providerNotFound and locales [en_US, en]
```